# Is there any method to retrieve 12 records from MongoDB db after matching a the id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to fetch the data of 12 records from where my id match.

For example, if the user enter a id which match with my database column id then from that match column id in database i want to fetch 12 records.

```
  const refxna=await Member.find({memberno:signuprefno}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(12)
```

I am writing the above query to match the data but it had return only a match data from database not its upper 12 records . I had use `$natural:-1` for bottom searching as i want to fetch the above table records after the match is found.

> I am implementing a sort of linked list query in which a third user
> whose reference id match with second user id and that "second user
> reference id" match with the "first user id". The table is
> has column of memberno (as user id) and refmno (as reference user id)

Answer (score 0):

Not found any problem with your query

Are you sure the records exist more than 1

please log the result from this command to review your data again

Comment: No the record doesn't exist more than 1 but I want to fetch all the 12 records above from where the match found.

Comment: Got your question now @Beren - seems like it is impossible, don't have any condition to we can do that :(